# In Spark is counting the records in an RDD expensive task?

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark

In Hadoop, when I use an inputformat reader the logs at the job level report how many records were read, it also displays the byte count etc.

In Spark when I use the same inputformat reader I get non of those metrics.

So I'm thinking that I would use the inputformat reader to populate the rdd, and then just publish the number of records in the rdd (size of the rdd).

I know that `rdd.count()` returns the size of the rdd.

However, the cost of using `count()` is not clear to me?  For example:

- Is it a distributed function?  Will each partition report its count and the counts are summed and reported?  Or is the entire rdd brought into the driver and counted?
- After executing the `count()` will the rdd still remain in memory or do I have to explicitly cache it?
- Is there a better way to do what I want to do, namely count the records before operating on them?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Is it a distributed function? Will each partition report its count
>      and the counts are summed and reported? Or is the entire rdd brought
>      into the driver and counted?

Count is distributed. In spark nomenclature, count is an "Action". All actions are distributed. Really, there are only a handful things that bring all of the data to the driver node and they are generally well documented (eg take, collect etc)

> After executing the count() will the rdd still remain in memory or do
>      I have to explicitly cache it?

No, the data will not be in memory. If you want it to be, you need to explicitly cache before counting. Spark's lazy evaluation will not make any computations until an Action is taken. And no data will be stored in memory after an Action unless there was a cache call.

> Is there a better way to do what I want to do, namely count the
>      records before operating on them?

Cache, count, operating seems like a solid plan

Comment: Actually it is a bit funny: for rdd count is a distributed operation, however for dataset looks like it is not:   def count(): Long = withCallback("count", groupBy().count()) { df =>
    df.collect(needCallback = false).head.getLong(0)
  } . Any idea why?

Comment: @KonstantinKulagin The df that it is bringing into memory in this case is a DF with 1 number, the number of rows of the original DF

Comment: For the counting operations, you may use Acummulators.

Comment: @David , so you are saying rdd.cache().count() will work better (or) someRDD = rdd.cache();   long numberOfRows = rdd.count(). , which one is correct ?

Comment: Computationally, they're equivalent

Comment: @David but groupBy is a shuffle operation, no?