# how to check RDD is empty efficiently?

Tags: performance, scala, apache-spark

I used spark `RDD.isEmpty` after I used the `filter`. But I think it cost much time for large data because `isEmpty` is action operation with `take(1)`.

here is example code.

```
val data = sc.parallelize(Seq(("a", 1), ("a", 2), ("b", 2), ("b", 3), ("c", 1)))
.reduceByKey(_+_)
.filter(_._2 > 5)
//Array[(String, Int)] = Array()

if(!data.isEmpty()){
    //running code...
}
```

Is there an efficient way to check, whether the data value is empty or not?

Comment: why not use data.count() inside if loop?

Comment: I don't think it is appropriate for large data.

Comment: *But I think it cost much time for large data* This feels more like a gut feeling. Did you benchmark your code? Is this the actual bottleneck?

Comment: When I saw Spark UI, the `Duration` on `Completed Jobs` was in minutes.
If I remove `isEmpty()`, The overall execution time has improved.

Comment: Please refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36723963/in-spark-is-counting-the-records-in-an-rdd-expensive-task. The answer states that the count operation is distributed & fast.

Comment: @SreeHarisshVenu take(1) should be even better, it only reads one record onto the driver.

Comment: The reason your overall execution time has improved is because Spark hasn't actually done anything.  Remember that RDDs are lazy, and your `parallelize`/`reduceByKey`/`filter` operations will not run until there is an action at the end.  `isEmpty` is a very fast operation compared to anything else you can do for this kind of check.

Comment: Which is faster among `take(1)` and `isEmpty()`?

Comment: @S.Kang `isEmpty` uses `take(1)` internally so they are basically identical for runtime.  In either case, they are very cheap, what takes time is the evaluation of the RDD, so the loading of data  and any other transformations, particularly wide operations that require a shuffle, will all have a larger effect.

Comment: I think the key to your problem is why you need the  `if (rdd.isEmpty)` block.  You might not need it at all or there might be a better way to accomplish what you want than checking if the RDD is empty.

Comment: After using `filter`, I used `if(!data.isEmpty)` to check whether there is data or not.
If there is data, I want to execute my code with other transformation operation.

Comment: Consider what would those other transformations do if the RDD is empty. If they end up giving the same result (for a simple example, just `map`) it may be faster to remove the check.

Answer (score 4):

`RDD.isEmpty` is the most efficient.  It does the least amount of work possible.

Remember that and RDD is not data, it's an execution plan.  It's not possible to check if there's data in an RDD without actually evaluating it, so you must execute an action and check the result.

If you need to check if an RDD is empty before the final action you can `persist` it first to cache the intermediate state so it won't need to be reevaluated in later jobs.

Answer (score 3):

As you have already said, rdd.isEmpty is an action, unless you refactor the code to remove the if condition (using more functional style instead of imperative style), the inefficiency cannot be removed. The simplest solution, as already suggested, could be to use cache the rdd before calling isEmpty, so that the transformations will be executed only once if you have enough cache memory.

As I am not aware of, what you want as part of "if(data.isEmpty())", the only suggestion I could give is, rdd.map, rdd.foreach etc are perfectly valid even for empty RDD. "if(data.isEmpty())" could be one way of approaching the solution. If you could give a more detail of the problem, we could suggest a functional approach.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!
I wonder how can I use `cache`?
Is `val data = sc.parallelize(Seq(("a", 1), ("a", 2), ("b", 2), ("b", 3), ("c", 1)))
.reduceByKey(_+_)
.filter(_._2 > 5).cache` what you mean??

Comment: That is exactly what I meant.